# Why do we need the running avg in batch normalization? Why not just divide by the number of iterations?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, batch-normalization

In the training phase of [Batch normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) we keep moving average of the activations in every layer so that we can use those "moving averages" in the test time. My question is why do we need to take moving average? We can approximate the mean by taking the mean of the activations in every layer in each iteration and then dividing by the number of batches and then use it in the test time.  For example, why not do something like:

```
AVG = 0        
while(# of iterations of training)  
     AVG = AVG + mean(activations of 3rd hidden layer)        
AVG_used_in_test = AVG / number of iterations
```

instead of the moving average?

Comment: Can you provide any context for this? What are you asking about?

Comment: i changed the question details and added a reference to a paper.

Comment: Thank you for doing so. I don't know this topic well enough to understand the question fully, but I suspect it will be clear enough to be answerable to people who work in that area. I also edited your question somewhat for more colloquial English. Please ensure it still says what you want it to.

Comment: What's wrong with using a moving average?

Comment: Aaron. i just want to know its intuition, why don't we just divide the activations by the number of iterations in the test time?

Comment: I'm also interested.I took the Andrew Ng course and still very confused about why do we need running average and not simple average.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/609110/why-do-we-use-moving-averages-in-evaluation-process-for-batch-normalization-laye/624018#624018

Answer (score 1):

Approximating the mean by taking the mean of the activations in every layer in each iteration and then dividing by the number of batches would give equal weight to all the batches. But all batches can't be given same weight because each batch won't be representing the training set because of sampling without replacement within each epoch. Also during training parameters get updated so in intial epochs the batch means wont be an accurate estimate because parameters will have random initialization and they might change rapidly in initial epochs.