# Why do we use moving averages in evaluation process for Batch Normalization layer?

Tags: model-evaluation, moving-average, batch-normalization

I have seen many links about MA for batch normalization but nothing answered my question.

In Batch normalization, you get means and variance for each mini-batches in the training process. And the default process, you calculate through the moving average.

Those mini-batches are chosen randomly so there is no higher priority for the recent mini-batch.
But why should we calculate the mean and variance for the evaluation process with MA and not just the normal average?

Answer (score 1):

The mean and variance of each mini-batch varies and each one may not represent the original input distribution fully. Also in the presence of outliers, the statistics of mini-batch containing them might be biased towards the outliers. So in order to avoid equal weightage assignment to each mini-batch moving average is used.